# Unable to modify existing AWS RDS. Getting InvalidParameterCombination error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an existing RDS in my account. I want to modify the RDS settings.
But whenever I click on modify after selecting the DB, i get the following error.

> Cannot find version 8.0.11 for mysql (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 4f73c65c-8bf9-4e3f-9fab-5b0c0940f09b)

I have the `engine version as 8.0.11`.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been an infamous AWS RDS issue. Basically their way of force pushing customers to upgrade. I recommend trying a higher version like 8.0.15 or 16. All supported versions are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html).

Comment: I started having this problem with MySQL 5.7.23 today as well.  My instance was running fine for years.  Last week I upgraded it to 5.7.23 without any problems.  Today I can't make any configuration changes and I can no longer connect to the read-replica of the same database.

Comment: Yeah, I faced this issue too sometime back. Try 5.7.26, it should work for you

Comment: My issue turned out to be an internal problem at Amazon.  Once they resolved it everything worked again.